# What is the right way to fill an array inside an object?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I want to make a deckeditor where you can choose with artwork you take from which set. For this reason I like to add all possibilities of this a Card to my object for easier handling later.

```js
class Card_possibilities {
    public id: number;
    public cardname: string;
    public edition: string;
    constructor(id: number, cardname: string, edition: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cardname = cardname;
        this.edition = edition;
    }
}
class Deck_List{
    id: number;
    cardname: string;
    quantity: number;
    _possibilities: Card_possibilities[];
    constructor(id: number, quantity: number, cardname: string, _possibilities: Card_possibilities[]=[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.cardname = cardname;
    }
    public set possibilities(CardArray: Card_possibilities[]){
        this._possibilities = CardArray;
     }
}
let cardnames_obj: Deck_List=new Deck_List(43,2,"Cancel");

let singleCard1:Card_possibilities= {id: 43, cardname: "Cancel", edition: "10E"};
let singleCard2:Card_possibilities= {id: 1227, cardname: "Cancel", edition: "AKH"};
let CardArray:Card_possibilities[]=[];
CardArray.push(singleCard1);
CardArray.push(singleCard2);

cardnames_obj.possibilities(CardArray); //<-- error
```

Have a look at StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zwqpxp
But when I try to fill the possibilities i get the error:

Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Card_possibilities[]' has no compatible call signatures.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**Solution: use Setter the right way:**
cardnames_obj.possibilities = CardArray;

Comment: What line is the error coming from? Can you create a reproduction on StackBlitz?

Comment: Sorry the last line:
cardnames_obj.possibilities(CardArray);

Comment: When you are creating object with name 'cardnames_obj2', why are you doing setting possibilities to 'cardnames_obj' ?

Comment: Sorry again copy paste error thats just a snippet from my other code correct line should be:
let cardnames_obj: Deck_List;

Comment: @LazarLjubenović: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zwqpxp
Yes it can be reproduced

Comment: I think what it means is your function possibilities() has no return type defined. Also, you are nowhere creating a new object of type Deck_List.

Comment: @AshishPandey added init for the object:
let cardnames_obj: Deck_List=new Deck_List(43,2,"Cancel");
Updated stackblitz too.

Why should a setter have an return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class method:

```
    public set possibilities(CardArray: Card_possibilities[]){
        this._possibilities = CardArray;
     }
```

is a setter, one of the features of the [typescript classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

By declaring that method with the `set` keyword, it means that whenever you write the `possibilities` property of a `Deck_List`, the function will run (instead of trying to modify the `possibility` field, which doesn't even exist), so:

`cardnames_obj.possibilities = CardArray;`

Will trigger the `set` function. You're trying to calling it directly instead, which is wrong:

`cardnames_obj.possibilities(CardArray);`// this fails

So your problem has nothing to do with arrays, but with the way you're using the `possibilities` setter.

Now, depending upon your tsc configuration, you may have another typing related errors, like lack of return type in function signatures and the likes, I'm not sure about this (but I think the setters don't need type signature).